# Is ValueConverter called after querying?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1

I'm using `ValueConverter` for column encryption in my ASP.NET Core project.

I have to check against email address duplication (which is encrypted by `aes-gcm`).
When I execute `Where(x => x.Email == email)` then nothing is found in the result.

So I guess, the `ValueConverter` was called after querying.
If my guess is correct then what can I do?
Is there any other solution?

Comment: With a lack of code in your question, I can't be more specific than advising to encrypt the input email address before checking if it exists in your database.

Comment: I just read an article about it [here](https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/233708-using-value-converter-for-custom-encryption-of-field-on-entity-framework-core-2-1), which states that your query values should be converted before executed. Perhaps you have a casing problem instead?

Comment: @ChrisPickford I think your suggestion makes sense. I figured out what my problem is. I'm using encryption with random IV (Nonce). so everytime I encrypt, the cipher has changed. therefore, the input email address was not matched. thanks for your comment by the way :)

Comment: Glad you figured it out, you could add what you did as an answer below in case it helps someone else out.

Comment: @ChrisPickford I will. I'm noob in this community. so your treat really helps me. a lot. sorry for my english though :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what my problem is.
I'm using data encryption with random IV(Nonce).
therefore, the cipher changes everytime when I compare email address.
so, I decided to make sure what my IV is, and input email has to
encrypt with that IV.

Thanks a lot all of you :)

- I solved this problem. It's bit hacky, but it worked.
  I added hmac to cipher. then I compare hmac between
  input email and column. hope this solution helps you guys :)

Comment: @Silvermind Oh, I didn't realized that. thank you :)